# Archive Errors [Provisioning Profile, App ID, and code Signing]

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, archive, submission

I have been trying to upload my first app to the app store, but I am having trouble.  Initially i was able to archive the app, but the export button was greyed out.  I found out that this was because I had archived it with my personal team profile and not my agent profile.  Unfortunately, after switching I am getting these three errors.
Here are some helpful Screenshots:

---

[image: Identity]

---

[image: Signing]

---

[image: Signing]

---

[image: Certificates]

---

[image: AppID]

---

[image: Device]

---

[image: DevProvision]

---

[image: DistProvision]

---

Answer (score 0):

I made lots of changes at once, but they seemed to fix the issue, so I'll tell you what I did.  First, make sure you have a distribution and development certificate AND provisioning license created at developer.apple.com AND download them and run them so they are installed on you computer.  Next, make sure that you have the correct license in any code signing sections in Xcode.  Finally, make sure that the build team is your "agent" profile, not your "personal team" profile.